# Sending data from Knockout.JS using AJAX

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

This is working for me; the request is going through when I click on the UI element.

```
    self.removeTweet = function(tweet) {
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: nodeApiUrl + 'twitter/remove_tweet/',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({'index': $('#removeFromQueue').val() }),
                dataType: 'json',
                error: $.osf.handleJSONError
            });
        self.tweets.remove(tweet);
    };
```

Here is the Knockout.JS loop

```
<div id = "foo">
    <!-- ko foreach: tweets -->

        <input id = "queuedTweet" data-bind="value: tweet"/>
        <a  class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.queueSubmit" >
            Send
        </a>
        <a id = "removeFromQueue" data-bind = "click: $parent.removeTweet, value: $index" class="btn btn-danger">
            Delete
        </a>

       </br>

     <!-- /ko -->
   </div>
```

I want to send the value of `$index` using AJAX, but

`data: JSON.stringify({'index': $('#removeFromQueue').val() })`

is not returning the value.  How can I send this data using AJAX?  I thought binding `$index` to `value` would be the solution.

Comment: show the start of the loop its in, show variable off your appModel

Comment: what does `{'index': $('#removeFromQueue').val() }` resolve to in your console?

Comment: You are using value on a `a` tag?

Comment: @pherris it resolves to 0.

Comment: @GôTô yes, it seemed like poor practice but I know of no other way to send the current index value

Comment: @johnsmith You can use `self.tweets.indexOf(tweet)`

Comment: @GôTô can you post that as an answer?  That worked! thank you

Comment: @johnsmith Done, you're welcome :) By the way, id's should be unique on the DOM. With your `foreach binding` you end up with several items with id "queuedTweet" and "removeFromQueue". You should remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the index as the value on the anchor, you can retrieve it with `self.tweets.indexOf(tweet)`:

```
self.removeTweet = function(tweet) {
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: nodeApiUrl + 'twitter/remove_tweet/',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({'index': self.tweets.indexOf(tweet) }),
            dataType: 'json',
            error: $.osf.handleJSONError
        });
    self.tweets.remove(tweet);
};
```